# Flash 5 / as2 text ignoring alpha on Chrome - works elsewhere

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a very old site which uses a Flash 5 interface to browse second hand cars for sale.

It's been working fine for the past 6 years, but is suddenly going wrong on Chrome on the PC.

http://www.gwsmotors.co.uk/showroom/

The descriptive text should only appear on roll-over. It does this correctly for me on Internet Explorer, Firefox and Safari (PC), but not on Chrome 22.0.1229.94 m. Have tested on Windows XP and Window 7, untested on a Mac.

I can't currently find the original .fla file and also don't have Flash 5 any more so am hoping this is fixable without needing to touch the .swf!

Has anyone experienced this before + does anyone have any fixes?

Many thanks

Comment: Chrome uses its own version of Flash, so there’s probably the problem. You can’t do much about it though, other than to hope that an update will randomly fix this.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to force Chrome to use one of the plugin forms of the Flash player, or whether you could do what the sites that choose not to support IE do and just put up a message "please view me in an ancient browser."